# Rails 4 / Heroku smart expire cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, heroku

We have in our application some blocks which are cached.

According to some login we sometimes modify some of them, and in this case we have a logic that expires the relevant blocks.

When we perform changes in the code, we need to expire these blocks via console. In this case we need to detect and be precise with the exact logic in order to expire all modified blocks. For example, if we change header html of closed streams, it will look like:

```
a = ActionController::Base.new
Stream.closed.each {|s| a.expire_fragment("stream_header_#{s.id}") }; nil
```

Actually, I think that **must be a more generic way** to simply compare cached blocks with how it should be rendered, and **expire only blocks which their html is different that their cached version**.

I wonder if there is a gem that does this task, and if not - if somebody has already written some deploy hook to do it.

============== UPDATE ============

**Some thought:**

In a rake task one can **get the cached fragment**, as long as you know which fragments you have.
For example, in my case I can do:

```
a = ActionController::Base.new
Stream.each do |s|
  cached_html = a.read_fragment("stream_header_#{s.id}")
     :
     :
```

If I could generate the **non-cached html** I could **simply compare them**, and expire the cached fragment in case they are different.

Is it possible?
How heavy do you think this task will be?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all easy to answer with so little code.

You can use the

```
cache @object do 
  render somthing
end
```

So based on the hash of the object the cache will invalided itself. This is also true for the rendering template as Rails will create a has on this also and combined it with the hash of the object to invalidate it properly. This also can work at a deeper level and in this way it is possible to invalidate an entire branch of the render tree.

Let me point you toward the documentation of Rails and the Russian doll caching.
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

There was also a great video on the caching by these guys:
https://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-4-zombie-outlaws

They are free, but it look like you have to register now.

I hope this is in the right direction for your need.